# Binomial tree option pricing drawing in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to create binomial tree in matlab like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W18Qe.png

The values are generated by :

```
 [Price, Option] = binprice(52, 50, 0.1, 2/12, 1/12, 0.4, 0, 0)
```

And the values are :

```
Price =

   52.0000   58.3648   65.5088
         0   46.3293   52.0000
         0         0   41.2769


Option =

    2.0824         0         0
         0    4.2620         0
         0         0    8.7231
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

With the data you generated, you can use [`treeview`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/fininst/treeviewer.html) from the `fininst` toolbox, like this

```
treeviewer(Price)
```

I don't have a matlab at hand right now to test, but this should be fine

Comment: Error using treeviewer (line 153)
Input argument 'Tree' not recognized as a valid tree.